One-Dimensional Skew-Hermitian Matrix of (1, 0) forms
When working with connections on hermitian line bundles, we often represent them as skew-hermitian matrices $A$ of $(1, 0)$ forms. My understanding is that this means that $\bar A = -A$. However, it seems to me that then $\bar A$ should be of type $(0, 1)$ and $-A$ of type $(1, 0)$ - a contradiction (?). Is there something I'm overlooking that would resolve this?
Edit: "We often represent them as ..." should read "We often represent them locally as ...". I'm primarily concerned with local properties here.

You’re conflating two independent properties of the Chern connection. When you work with a unitary frame, the connection matrix is skew-hermitian. When you work with a holomorphic frame, the connection matrix consists of $(1,0)$-forms.

I think that in the books I’m working with, there are proofs that involve working with a holomorphic unitary frame - is that never done / can we not guarantee the existence of such a frame? If that is done, then are there implications on the connection matrix?

There can be no holomophic unitary frame. This is an immediate consequence of the C-R equations (or, if you prefer, of your paradox above).

So sorry, one last follow up - could the trivial bundle have a unitary holomorphic frame? Equivalently, could we have local unitary holomorphic frames? That's the main setting I'm considering; I didn't clarify that, sorry.

Nope. Go back to basic complex analysis and show that the only holomorphic function with constant modulus is a constant.
